# Where shading "smooth" and "flat" are located inside Blender 2.80?

Tags: modeling, shaders

I would like to know where the realtime rendering options for faces "smooth" and "Flat" are located inside Blender 2.80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3D Viewport, while in *Object Mode*, under the header's "*Object*" menu

[image]

To use it in Edit mode for some selected faces, look again in the Viewport's header, but this time under *Mesh > Shading > Smooth/Flat Faces*

[image]